# UINavigationBar custom color with Embeded UInavigatonController in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

It's a silly question, but I really want to know, how can I add custom color in my default `UINavigationBar` which actually added to my `viewController` from `Editor` > `Embed in` > `NavigationController`.

I add this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:244/255 green:119/255 blue:39/255 alpha:1.0]];
```

In my `AppDelegat` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` but nothing happen. Can any one please tell me how to do that? 
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view controller add this in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setBarTintColor:[UIColor yourColor];
```

if your navigation controller is your root view controller (first view controller in storyboard) you can use this in app delegate:

```
[[(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController navigationBar] setBarTintColor:[UIColor yourColor]];
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I want to do it from `AppDelegate`, so that I don't have to add this in every single `viewController`.

Comment: You don't have to do it in every view controller unless you want to change the color.
Put that code in your the first view controller that is going to show.

Another way to do that is to have a reference of your navigation controller in AppDelegate

Comment: Can you please explain about the "reference of your navigation controller in AppDelegate".